# Android - Getting DisplayMetrics in a class

Tags: android

I am working on a custom class to help resizing layouts from other classes.

Here's the class

```
public class LayoutResize{

    Context context;
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

    public int width(int sizeX)
    {
        //((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        //getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        //getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

        int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels * sizeX / 100;
        Log.d("displayMetrics", "dismet" + displayMetrics);
        return screenWidth;
    }

    public int height(int sizeY)
    {
        //((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        //getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        //getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

        int screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels * sizeY / 100;
        return screenHeight;
    }

}
```

Before, I use the class like :

```
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    LayoutResize layoutResize = new LayoutResize();
    RelativeLayout mLayout= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mLayout);
            int mLayoutWidth = layoutResize.width(90, displayMetrics);

...
}
```

To resize `mLayout`'s width to 90% of window size.

I used to pass `displayMetrics` value from every class I use `LayoutResize` class from. Used to be like this :

```
public int width(int sizeX, displayMetrics)
{
...
}
```

Now, as seen in the `LayoutResize` class, I'm trying to just pass the percentage value.

I've tried using those commented codes but every code returns `getWindowManager` returns null value.. What am I missing here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `LayoutResize` class, you create a new `displayMetrics` instead of using the one that you instantiated on your `onCreate`.

You can create a constructor in your `LayoutResize` and pass the `displayMetrics` as parameter, like this:

```
public class LayoutResize{

DisplayMetrics displayMetrics;

public LayoutResize (DisplayMetrics displayMetrics){
    this.displayMetrics = displayMetrics;
}

public int width(int sizeX)
{
    int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels * sizeX / 100;
    Log.d("displayMetrics", "dismet" + displayMetrics);
    return screenWidth;
}

public int height(int sizeY)
{
    int screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels * sizeY / 100;
    return screenHeight;
}

}
```

And then you instantiate like this:

```
LayoutResize layoutResize = new LayoutResize(displayMetrics);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hohoho it helped a lot! So I have to make a habit of creating a constructor for every class as such, I knew it was about basic stuff! Thanks!